# How to remove wet mud from leather shoes

Tags: cleaning, shoes

My Leather shoes are covered in wet mud. They are Ahnu, Karma sandal shoes, with a stitched pattern. If I let it dry, they will be permanently disfigured. Do I hose them down, or wipe them and bring them in to my shoe guy?

Answer (score 1):

let it dry then brush it off. Any residue can be dabbed off with a wet cloth again leaving it to dry

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it can be hosed off.

However, these are suede shoes, which require a little more care than smooth leather. I would try wiping the mud off as gently as possible.

If that's not possible, hose them down, patting the water off right after. Then stuff them full of paper towels to absorb the moisture and use a suede brush (finger nail brush, if you lack the suede brush) to remove the water stains with more paper towels. Inside the shoes is the same treatment, but the sole may be irrecoverable from stains.

If there's any kind of mud stain, vinegar may help to remove it, with a suede brush.

Answer (score 0):

Hose them down. Stuff them with old newspapers, to keep the form in shape and soak up some water. Than put them near a radiator or some heat source, to speed up the drying, but not too close. If you can't hold your hand there.. it's too hot. Good luck